# Embedding a document from sharepoint/onedrive on office 365 into webapp

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint

I am wondering if its possible to within our webapp to embed a office document like word such user can edit the document.

I am using Azure AD to get a token for sharepoint and would like to open the document from the users files or site on sharepoint (alittle new to sharepoint so not sure i know the terms).

General I want the sales teams to maintain a document for each client, so listing clients and making it possible to create a document and edit the document that is stored on sharepoint.

If embeding the word web version is not possible, then just opening it from our site will also be okay. If anyone can point me to the right docs sites with rest api references and possible if there exists a .net c# client that would also be nice. 
I havent been able to find what i am looking for on google, possible because i dont know enough about sharepoint to search for the right thing.

Comment: Your best chance of getting an answer is to close this an re-post on SharePoint Stack Exchange (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). This isn't an Azure-related question.

Comment: Any updates on if this was reposted somewhere?